# Convergence of Random Variables ($X_n \xrightarrow{em} X$ implies that $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$)

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been reading the book "All of Statistics - A Concise Course in Statistical Inference" of Larry Wasserman, and there is something I don't understand and I will be happy If you can help me.

In page 74 while he tried to show the correctness of $X_n \xrightarrow{em} X$ implies that $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$:

Proof. Suppose that $X_n \xrightarrow{em} X$.
Fix $ \epsilon> 0$ . Then:
using Markov’s inequality:

$$ P(|X_n-X|> \epsilon) = P((X_n-X)^2> \epsilon^2) \leq \frac{E[(X_n-X)^2]}{\epsilon^2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$

But what happened if I choose $\epsilon=\frac{\sqrt{E\smash[b]{[(X_n-X)^2]}}}{n} \gt 0$ (for every $n \geq 0$), the phrase

$$\frac{E[(X_n-X)^2]}{\epsilon^2} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$

will not hold.

I understand in the proof he fixed $\epsilon$, but $\epsilon$ is fixed for specific $n$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi: You're making $\epsilon$ a function of $n$ so it's not fixed. In the proof, one fixes $\epsilon$ and then lets $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: But in page 65 in the book, epsilon used in similar inequality with function of n. So when epsilon can be function of n and when not?

Comment: In general $\epsilon$-$N$ formulation, the choice of $\epsilon$ must be free from anything else. I checked p65 of the book, but the choice of $\epsilon_n$ in line 13 is not the $\epsilon$ for an $\epsilon$-$N$ argument, but rather a parameter involved in the Hoeffding's inequality. Note that $\epsilon$ usually refers to a 'small quantity', so it need not be used only for $\epsilon$-$N$ arguments.

Comment: I don't understand your answer @SangchulLee, I will be happy for clarification and more detailed answer please. And moreover, what do you mean by $\epsilon -N$?

Comment: I don't see how there can be better explanation than what is given by Sangchul Lee. You should go back to Calculus and read the definition of  limit of  a sequence.

Comment: what means "em"? First time I see it.

Comment: @Ron: I'm gonna leave this to Sangchui Lee and Kavi Rama Murthy because I don't know what else to say except that defining $\epsilon$ as a function of $n$ is not the way to proceed.